# Embedded WildFly server: how to catch exceptions and display log message

Tags: wildfly

We've created an embedded WildFly server with `EmbeddedProcessFactory.createStandaloneServer(...)`, but any exceptions that happen in that server are eaten (they go to `/dev/null`?), so without those stacktraces in the console, it's hard to figure out which line is causing them.

How can we capture the exceptions and or log messages thrown by the embedded WildFly server?

Comment: [Related Errai issue link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ERRAI-1074)

Comment: This looks like a bug in WildFly https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-3205.